# Calculate sum in SQL and display it as another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used the following query for calculating credit of customers but the problem i want to calculate the sum of CREDIT column in another which just sum up the `CREDIT` and display in another column .Is there any way of doing this by modifying following query? 
Any help would be highly appreciable.

```
Select
    CUSTOMER_NAME
   ,TODAYS_TOTAL
   ,AMOUNT_RECIEVED
   ,DATE_SALE
   ,ITEM_MODEL
   ,QUANTITY
   ,CREDIT = (CASE 
      WHEN AMOUNT_RECIEVED=0 AND TODAYS_TOTAL>0 AND CREDIT =0 THEN TODAYS_TOTAL 
      WHEN AMOUNT_RECIEVED>0 AND TODAYS_TOTAL>0 AND CREDIT>=0 THEN (CREDIT+TODAYS_TOTAL)-AMOUNT_RECIEVED
      WHEN AMOUNT_RECIEVED>0 AND TODAYS_TOTAL=0 AND CREDIT >0 THEN (CREDIT-AMOUNT_RECIEVED)
      END) 
From CUSTOMER_CREDIT_RECORDS 
WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME='Saad NED'
```

Comment: Your question is (**very**) unclear. Please provide some sample data and the desired results.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is your query more understandably formatted:

```
Select CUSTOMER_NAME, TODAYS_TOTAL, AMOUNT_RECIEVED, DATE_SALE, ITEM_MODEL, QUANTITY,
       CREDIT = (CASE WHEN AMOUNT_RECIEVED=0 AND TODAYS_TOTAL>0 AND CREDIT=0
                      THEN TODAYS_TOTAL 
                      WHEN AMOUNT_RECIEVED>0 AND TODAYS_TOTAL>0 AND CREDIT>=0
                      THEN (CREDIT+TODAYS_TOTAL)-AMOUNT_RECIEVED
                      WHEN AMOUNT_RECIEVED>0 AND TODAYS_TOTAL=0 AND CREDIT>0
                      THEN (CREDIT-AMOUNT_RECIEVED)
                 END) 
From CUSTOMER_CREDIT_RECORDS
WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME = 'Saad NED';
```

You only have one customer, so most of the columns don't make sense for a daily total.  You can do:

```
Select CUSTOMER_NAME, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN AMOUNT_RECIEVED=0 AND TODAYS_TOTAL>0 AND CREDIT=0
                THEN TODAYS_TOTAL 
                WHEN AMOUNT_RECIEVED>0 AND TODAYS_TOTAL>0 AND CREDIT>=0
                THEN (CREDIT+TODAYS_TOTAL)-AMOUNT_RECIEVED
                WHEN AMOUNT_RECIEVED>0 AND TODAYS_TOTAL=0 AND CREDIT>0
                THEN (CREDIT-AMOUNT_RECIEVED)
           END) as CREDIT
From CUSTOMER_CREDIT_RECORDS
WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME = 'Saad NED'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

However, I'm mostly curious about the arithmetic in the `case` statements.  Do you have an aversion to adding values that are `0`?  It seems much simpler to do:

```
Select CUSTOMER_NAME, 
       SUM(CREDIT + TODAYS_TOTAL - AMOUNT_RECIEVED) as CREDIT
From CUSTOMER_CREDIT_RECORDS
WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME = 'Saad NED'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

This assumes that at least one of the `when` conditions is satisfied.

Comment: There may be more than one `Customers` with the same name so i want to calculate the `TOTAL_CREDIT SUM` of that particular Customer.

Comment: @CodeSniper . . . Then `group by` whatever id identifies the customer.  You should also include that in the `select` clause.